# newline options for braces for properties (C# VS 2005)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Simple really - in Tools, Options, Text Editor, C#, New Lines, New Line Options for braces, there is not an option for properties...

Or am I going mad and just can't find it?

EDIT: I am using an add-in  that is generating the code and reportedly uses the VS settings.... but doesn't seem to, so I've given up on this issue, it's not that important.

Comment: Odd - there isn't one in VS2008 either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there isn't; it uses the "methods" setting. Resharper may have more control, but has a price tag too.

Comment: it may be the add-in that isn't working properly, supposed to use those settings (http://www.csharper.net/blog/property_manager_update.aspx#property_manager_addin_for_visual_studio_2005.aspx)

oh well, useul addin nonetheless

Comment: Erm... who mentioned an add-in?

Answer (score 0):

For the outer braces of the property it's the same one as for methods (Place open brace on new line for methods).

Comment: I don't have 2005 handy, but in 2008 it applies to the inner (get/set) braces too.

Comment: You're right, I put the "get" statement all in one line, so it didn't auto-format it