# New line options for braces for properties

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know that Visual Studio 2005 did not support [new line options for braces for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729434/1506793), but I am trying to find out if Visual Studio 2012 does. Does anyone know if there is native support for this or of a free extension (i.e., not *Resharper*) that adds support for this?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I don't exactly get what you're after, but the I've got the "Productivity Power Tools 2012" (free tool) installed and I think you might want that.. (just keep typing, it'll change your code on the go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, still there is no options for this.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. :( Do you know of any extensions that add support for this?

Comment: I am testing now JustCode from Telerik (alas it is not free) and they have a code template expansion widget. You define your text and replaceable parts then call a keyboard combination to recall that code template and start to substitute the variable parts. I know it is not the same thing you asked for.

Comment: OK they have a formatting option for property in the coding style options. Not for the faint of heart

Comment: Hahaha - Thanks for all of your help, Steve. :)